# Postmark in PHP 5: Check if mail was bounced or successfull

Tags: php, html, postmark

I am using Postmark Email App in my PHP 5 code.

I have tried to send email.

But how to check if the email was bounced or sent successfully?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Rackesh, the fastest and most reliable way to know if an email was bounced is to setup a Bounce Hook url so that you will have a server that can be notified immediately upon a message bouncing http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-bounces.html#bounce-hooks If you're using php, I have a gist https://gist.github.com/jptoto/5265126 which illustrates and Inbound example but would be very trivial to modify to use for a bounce hook.

Comment: How will I come to know which Email was bounced. Do I get any parameter in QueryString of url.

Comment: Rakesh, you'll receive a json body in the POST.